# Ionic select is missing the top confirm part in iOs

Tags: ios, select, ionic-framework

So I use the standard code for select like so:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select" ng-class="{ 'has-error-lr' : postTaskForm.type.$invalid  && postTaskForm.$submitted, 'valid-lr' : postTaskForm.type.$valid  && postTaskForm.$submitted}">
      <div class="input-label"> Video Job Type: </div>
      <select ng-model="postTask.type" name="type" ng-required="true">
        <option>Commercial</option>
        <option>Interview</option>
        <option selected>Training Lesson</option>
        <option>Live Event Recording</option>
      </select> 
    </label>
```

When render in iOs, it look like this:

[image]

As you see the top confirm part is totally missing. What is wrong? How can I get the confirm button in native iOs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in your app.js file you should see this piece of code

```
angular.module('config', [])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

try setting `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);` instead of true

so this is final code

```
angular.module('config', [])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

obviously some of your code will be different the important thing is just changing the hideKeyboardAccessoryBar to false.

Comment: OMG! That simple?! You have no idea how much headache I had trying to figure this out! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For people who came accros this issue in a more recent version of Ionic Angular (with Typescript f.i.), you need to set the setting proposed by @Jess Patton in your `app.component.ts` to `false` like this:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

declare let Keyboard: any;

@component({
  templateUrl: 'index.html'
})
export class myApp {
  constructor (platform: Platform) {

    platform.ready().then((source) => {
      Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);
    });
  }
}
```

(Note that you can also provide a callback to this method as it's second parameter)

Hopefully this helps someone not to waste their time like I just did.